# ReactNative - want to make the interpolate of Animated work according to the scroll direction

Tags: react-native

I use `interpolate` to resize the component at the top of the `scroll view`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Animated } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


export default class App extends React.Component {

scrollY = new Animated.Value(0);

  animation = () => {
    return (this.scrollY.interpolate ({
          inputRange: [0, 250],
          outputRange: [95, 0],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }));
    }



  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={{ height: this.animation(),backgroundColor:'red' }}>
       <Text>test</Text>
      </Animated.View>
       <Animated.ScrollView
         style={{ flex:1 }}
         justifyContent={{ flexGrow:1 }}
         onScroll={Animated.event(
          [
            {
               nativeEvent: {contentOffset:{y:this.scrollY}}
            }
         ]
        )}>
          <Text style={{height:1500}}>test</Text>
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

I want that the top view gets bigger when scrolling up and the top view gets smaller when scrolling down.

In the current code
The inputRange of interpolate is fixed at [0,250].

if Beyond 250 The top view is always 0.
How can I make it my way?

my expo snack

> https://snack.expo.io/HyR-7M_qB

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have a similar question.